# png snapshot of a specific swf frame

Tags: actionscript

I have two swfs. the first is my as3 application. the second one is contains 50 odd frames. The first swf has only two elements: a text box wherein the user types an integer (the frame number of the second swf actually) and a border container 100 x 300. When the user keys in an integer in the first swfs text box, I need to access the second swf from the first one, take a bitmap snapshot of the frame specified by the user, convert to png (minimum resolution 300 dpi) and display it inside the first swfs border container.

Can anyone guide me on how to take a bitmap snapshot (or convert) a specific frame of an external swf and pass it back to the master (controlling) swf?

Thanks

Comment: Did you searched on Google, even in stackoverflow ?

Comment: For those who may be looking for an answer, i solved it myself. Thanks to all those who took time to look at the query.

Comment: And why dont you post the way you solve it.